# Recursively patch type definition

Tags: typescript, recursive-type

I'm trying to write a generic type that takes a type as a parameter (which could be a plain object, an array, a primitive, etc.) and remaps the value types when it is a plain object or an array to add some configuration directives described by a `Configuration` type.

Let's call that hypothetic modifier `Configurable<T>`. `T` could be any complexly nested entity. `Book` could be a value for `T` for example :

```ts
type Configuration = {
  $test: {
    option1: boolean;
    option2: string;
  }
};

type Book = {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  related: Array<string>;
};

type Result = Configurable<Book>;
```

I then want `Configurable<Book>` to correctly type-check the following expressions where the values could be the actual values or the configuration object :

```ts
const expr1: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "1",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: ["2", "3"]
}

const expr2: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "2",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: {
    $test: {
      option1: true,
      option2: "something"
    }
  },
  related: []
}

const expr3: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "3",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: ["2", {
    $test: {
      option1: true,
      option2: "something"
    }
  }]
}

const expr4: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "4",
  title: true, // ERROR: should be string or Configuration
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: ["2", "3"]
}

const expr5: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "5",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: {
    $test: {
      option1: true,
      option2: "something"
    }
  } // ERROR: should be an array of (string | Configuration)
}
```

Nested object or arrays should not be replaceable by `Configuration`, only where a primitive value is expected (see `expr5`).
Here is what I tried :

```ts
type Configuration = {
  $test: {
    option1: boolean;
    option2: string;
  };
};

type Configurable<T> = Record<string, any> extends T
  ? {
      [K in keyof T]: Configurable<T[K]> | Configuration;
    }
  : T extends Array<infer U>
  ? Array<Configurable<U>>
  : T;
```

But this makes `expr2` and `expr3` fail.

**[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBXATgQ2CxKAXigG8AoKKAEmAgGdgAuMyqqOMfRARhYCM4cADYQcCANxsqnbggBMLRlhQI0UqgF8p28uVCRYiVJlz9RAHgAqAPmJQAShADGcLABMLy1WgA0UcRA7CAAPOgR3eigrNgB%20VnZ2AG0AaShVKABrCBA4JGiAXRZ4ZHRsHHMIa1SCuwAfI1LTPAJJaShNNhYrKFDwyKgAQSxcEAtVJAgsKABVGzihkZwxkpNyyos5%20apuqX1waAAhIUz7CioUdyVgFTUNKHxgUWvb9TYcDGAACzcXn3usBBhHgIFdFqMvDcfDYdHtXAhGL0QmAsHxGmszJZjnBMnYSOd0mCAEQ8Im%20NiPZ5QIkACRwIxAUAACnBgHQsGT3p8flgWESAFIAOhSgsccAA7sIfJyqIDgXQwUkifIydSAMxEgrkTrkeGI0IoxTosqYqrY3FnNiXPkq8lUSkQPl0hnM1nsmUBbm-BLsWgMZg%20xKyVpom4YCB2xIcLitI1E%20hwAC2EG%200vanS02r0euASJRauKxhNFSxJzxPut6o9Dqd9KwjJZbKmHo%20329AuFoocEqlag9cpBiuVqoJVD9jBYo-Ywd4LDDEfaMhjiDjCeTqb76bYmi1OpzeawABZC011qWceWCZWiYfqygno6Hlhw-4APSvqAAUQcDgA8g4lB%20DBhHcKB%20Ggbw1A4aZVmLOQuTbXlqSFEUxUlaVIwHBUWCVW0q13IA)**

Comment: Doesn't `expr2` need a `related` property?  Am I taking crazy pills here?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you could use this definition of `Configurable`:

```
type Configurable<T> = T extends object ?
  { [K in keyof T]: Configurable<T[K]> } :
  T | Configuration;
```

[The `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) corresponds to any non-primitive, including arrays.  If `T extends object` is not true, then `T` is a primitive and you want to accept `T | Configuration`.  If `T extends object` is true, then you [map over its properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with `Configurable`.  This should automatically do the right thing with arrays and tuples, since [mapped tuples and arrays produce tuples and arrays](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

Let's try it out:

```
const expr1: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "1",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: ["2", "3"]
}

const expr2: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "2",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: {
    $test: {
      option1: true,
      option2: "something"
    }
  },
  related: []
}

const expr3: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "3",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: ["2", {
    $test: {
      option1: true,
      option2: "something"
    }
  }]
}
```

The above examples compile with no error as desired.  Let's check the errors:

```
const expr4: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "4",
  title: true, // ERROR: should be string or Configuration
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: ["2", "3"]
}

const expr5: Configurable<Book> = {
  id: "5",
  title: "Harry Potter",
  author: "J.K. Rowling",
  related: {
    $test: {
      option1: true,
      option2: "something"
    }
  } // ERROR: should be an array of (string | Configuration)
}
```

The errors you want are indeed produced.  Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwGYEsDmBXATgQ2CxKAXigG8AoKKAEmAgGdgAuMyqqOMfRARhYCM4cADYQcCANxsqnbggBMLRlhQI0UqgF8p28uVCRYiVJlz9RAHgAqAPmJQrUCAA86CACb0O-AFYQAxsBQAPxspFAA2gDSUKpQANYQIHBIDgC6LPDI6Ng45hDW0Wl2mlBMbI4APkbZpngEknr64NAAQkLx9hRUKO5KwCpqGlD4wKL9g+psOBjAABZwWBOqU1RYEMJ4EH1QAIJYuCAWyis2OlLk-oiMTs5gWHw1Jrn5Fu1w8XYk3bE7AEQ8P4AGjYo3GUD+AAkcAcQFAAApwYB0LDA6azBZLCEAKQAdFFcVAAEpwADuwhWaLWGy2Owif3kwIhAGY-mlyJo9FcEDcXPdFE8cmZLO9Pl02L0WAyqSMUGMIFLobCEUiUTKZvNFiwflRaAxmKx2OxZA1HgMMBAQUaZFwGgK-vQ4ABbCDzSnSKCcrRWqDrTZ0OnszmXa5BPlYZmZYxCvIijpfQ2-KWsn1ghUQpVYOGI5EQVE+jWYqV4gnEskUtQyv20lj0xlAxO6uiMbUem1yM1YC0+o0mxD2x0ut2Vj1ez1Brmh273AAsUdqLzjHwTP0lEJnMrTLHNlqgAHo91AAKJEokAeSJSgWGGE7ig-GgJzUHCwgrqcnRmqxfxLhJJ5MpH1qwDWtpQbP5WQnEMeTDO4sAAVnnZ5hQKUUVwlf54M3OVwShGEsxVXN80-IscXxP9y0AthgO2VsjT1FtG2NW1eG3LtLTbDgWIUKVB1dOZ3SNMdSgPY9TwvK84BvO8HygcQ5IOHA4RSKAAAonzQKBqiyZD6kQABKDkgA)